# How to fix 'TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable ' in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I am building the VUI for a virtual assistant as a hobby project using pyttsx3 and SpeechRecognition.
i first made a function called `take_order()` then in the next function `run_agos()` i checked if `take_Order()` contains some keyword to start an other process, see this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import winsound
import wikipedia
import pyjokes
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_order():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alex' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
            else:
                return
            return command
    except pass



def run_agos():
    task = take_order()

    if 'play' in task:
        song = task.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in task:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        print(time)
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who is' in task:
        person = task.replace('who is', '')
        try:
            info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
            print(info)
            talk(info)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
            print(e.options)
            talk(person + 'may refer to')
            talk(e.options)
    elif 'what is' in task:
        thing = task.replace('what is', '')
        try:
            info = wikipedia.summary(thing, 1)
            print(info)
            talk(info)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
            print(e.options)
            talk(thing + 'may refer to')
            talk(e.options)
    elif 'joke' in task:
        joke = pyjokes.get_joke()
        talk(joke)
        print(joke)
    else:
        talk('I did not hear that, pleas repeat the command.')
    return run_agos()


while True:
    run_agos()
```

At first it works fine, however after a while I get `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` and the program shuts down. I also get the extit code: -1073741819 (0xC0000005).How can I fix this error so it will keep running the program?

Comment: Your take_order function will return None in two cases. After you call take_order() check to see that task is not None.

Comment: Suggest you to run the program in debug mode (may be in some IDE like pycharm), configure the program to stop at exception and observe where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in the take_order function, you are either returning nothing when an error occurs or returning nothing as well when 'alexa' isn't in the command. Then your code checks `if 'play' in task`. Here, task is None since nothing was returned. This is your main issue. I would suggest returning a specific string or a value for example -1. Then, right after `task = take_order()`, check if task is that value.
for example

```
def take_order():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alex' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
            else:
                return -1
            return command
    except: return -1

def run_agos():
    task = take_order()
    if task == -1: return
    ...
```

One more thing: You always do `return run_agos()` at the end of run_agos() which recursively calls itself. This is bad practice since you already have a `while True` loop that calls the function forever. I would suggest removing the return statement in the end of `run_agos`